# Outputting objects from json in csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv

I'm trying to find a way to output objects json and save them in csv file, i was trying to use loop 'for in' in 'loop for ' but the problem is that property and length object are different

```
data json:

[ 
{"name":"Googlebot","htmlimports":true,"objectfit":true,"geolocation":true,"histor":true,"es5object":true,"strictmode":true,"es5string":true}, 

{"name":"Bing","htmlimports":false,"geolocation":true,"history":true,"es5object":true,"strictmode":true,"es5string":true}, 

{"name":"iE","htmlimports":true,"svgclippaths":true,"geolocation":true,"history":true,"ie8compat":false,"strictmode":true,"es5string":true,"es5syntax":true} ]


const stringify = require('csv-stringify');
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('./googleBot.json','utf8', (err, dataa) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const dates  = JSON.parse(dataa)

  let data = [];
  let columns = {
    value: 'value',
    Googlebot: 'Googlebot',
    Bing: 'Bing',
    iE: 'iE',
  };

  for(i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
    for (var prop in dates) {
      data.push([prop, `${dates[0][prop]}`, `${dates[1][prop]}`, `${dates[2][prop]}`]);
    }
  }


  stringify(data, { header: true, columns: columns }, (err, output) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.writeFile('my.csv', output, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('my.csv saved.');
    });
  });
});
```

expected result:

[image]

Comment: the expected result doesn't seem to bear much relation to the input JSON...there are no "autocomplete", "multiple", "min" or "max" properties in any of your object. And it's unclear how any of this constitutes "comparing" two objects...you simply seem to be want to work through each one and outputting the value of some of the properties.

Comment: Your question is not clear? Your sample data and your result image aren't  match

Comment: I mean expect result is just a example

Comment: ye it is more like going through each value and outputting than comparing you right

Comment: "expect result is just a example" ok but it would be a lot more easy for us to understand if it was an example based on what you'd expect the input data you've shown to produce. Otherwise we can't exactly be sure what the rules are. Right now it looks random.

Comment: ok i understand i corrected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your objects can contain different properties, you first need to gather a list of all possible properties.

You can do this by creating a temporary array to hold properties, and iterating over your objects and pushing properties in this array, if they're not already there.

```
var allProps = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  for (var prop in dates[i]) {
    if (!allProps.includes(prop)) {
      allProps.push(prop);
    }
  }
}
```

After that, it's just a matter of constructing your rows properly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allProps.length; i++) {
  var prop = allProps[i];
  if (prop == 'name') continue;  //skip the name property, it's alrady in the columns

  var row = []
  row.push(prop);  //first entry in the row is the property name

  for (var k = 0; k < dates.length; k++) {
    row.push(`${dates[k][prop]}`);
  }

  data.push(row);
}
```

See this code running [here](https://repl.it/@mihaifm/csvStringify)

Output:

```
value,Googlebot,Bing,iE
htmlimports,true,false,true
objectfit,true,undefined,undefined
geolocation,true,true,true
histor,true,undefined,undefined
es5object,true,true,undefined
strictmode,true,true,true
es5string,true,true,true
history,undefined,true,true
svgclippaths,undefined,undefined,true
ie8compat,undefined,undefined,false
es5syntax,undefined,undefined,true
```